# Uncaught (in Promise) DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, dom

I'm seeing the follow error in our HTML 5 JavaScript video player implementation, only on Android + Chrome Mobile:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture

What is the cause of this error and what is the right way to avoid it going forward?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Uncaught (in promise) DOMException while playing AUDIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54719283/google-chrome-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-while-playing-audio)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a webview this will work.

```
webviewSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Am also faced same issue.Finally issue is fixed. Webview height updated as wrap_content to match_parent.
Add below code:

```
webviewSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Now error is gone and url loaded successfully. Hope it will useful someone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to implement some sort of autoplay feature? Autoplay has been disabled on newer versions of Android. Here's the issue thread featuring a long discussion on autoplay ability if you're curious: http://chromium-bugs.chromium.narkive.com/cW5IXVgj/issue-178297-in-chromium-android-chrome-does-not-allow-applications-to-play-html5-audio-without-an

You can get it to work by triggering play() on a different event, such as on a button click or on video load.

Comment: Any chance you could provide an example? of the video load autoplay on android?